# How to remove unknown line break (special character) in text file?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, special-characters, text-rendering, ultraedit

I have a text file which shows a *Line Break* in UltraEdit if we replace a special character in text file manually it works fine. [Unknown Line Break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9W7y.jpg). I have to change it manually and then process the files.

Please let me know some way how to remove all occurrences of this character with VB.Net code.

If I replace ♀ in UltraEdit, it replaces *line break* with my desired string. But in my VB string I cannot use this character or *line break*.

Comment: If you use a hex editor to examine the file before and after manually editing it, you will be able to determine that. You *probably* want to use `VbCrLf` as the replacement.

Comment: It is a form-feed, ChrW(12) in vb.net code.  Common when the output was intended for a printer.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for such info can you show some exemplary code to work with ChrW(12)...? I will be greatful. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character you have in your file is the [form-feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_feed) character usually used as control character for a page break.

In **UltraEdit** in **Page Setup** configuration dialog (a printing related dialog) there is the option *Page break code* which has by default the decimal value 12 (hexadecimal 0C) which is the form-feed character.

A page break can be displayed in **UltraEdit** with a horizontal line across the document window on enabling **Show Page Breaks as Lines** in menu/ribbon **View**.

The form-feed character can be removed in **UltraEdit** with searching for `^b` on using a normal, non regular expression or an UltraEdit regular expression replace, or with searching for `\f` on using a Unix or Perl regular expression replace.

In VB.Net code `ChrW(12)` can be used to reference the form-feed control character as suggested already by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant).